# Symfony2 with PHP 5.4 built-in server

Tags: php

I'm trying to work with Symfony2 with the new PHP 5.4 and its built-in server.
I downloaded Symfony2 and unziped it on my server and added this router.php file like mentioned [here](http://michal-pipa.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-symfony2-with-php-54-built-in-web.html):

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        require 'Symfony/web/app.php';
    }

?>
```

The webserver itself works because if I replace `router.php` with something simple like `phpinfo();` it outputs it correct but with the mentioned `router.php` script the site remains white/blank. If I open developer tools it returns `500 Server error`.

I start the server like that:

```
/home/php54/php -S 0.0.0.0:88 router.php
```

On my shell I have no output of a error message.

Comment: This may not be the answer, but have you installed the vendors for Symfony?

Comment: I downloaded 2.0.11 with Vendors: http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.0.11.zip Because I haven't installed Git.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. What do you apache2 error logs say?

Comment: Um, this works without Apache (built-in PHP server) so there isn't logged someting in the error logs of Apache :)

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of router and see what you get.  Probably an include file or possibly a permissions issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> /home/php54/php -S 0.0.0.0:88 router.php

You are trying to run server on privileged port, so either change port or run this as privileged user (not recommended).

Also you have modified router script and I think you've messed up with file paths. You are not specifying docroot in your command, so your current directory is your docroot (so it should be your project's web/ directory). But then path to the front controller in router.php is wrong (`Symfony/web/app.php`).

You should really *follow carefully* instructions from my blog post. So:

- change your current directory to your project's web/ directory,
- download router script: `wget https://raw.github.com/gist/1507820/b9583ab7f7f5e0e4e29806c38c6c361220b6468f/router.php`,
- run server: `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 router.php`.

This should work.

You can also try patch from [my pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3465) which adds simple command that just runs built-in PHP server.

Comment: strange the router script doesnt work for me , i have to rename app_dev.php into index.php to make it work properly.

Comment: This pull request is now integrated. One can now run `app/console server:run` or `app/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000` and modify app_dev.php to allow other systems on your network to access it (great for testing your app on mobile devices)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a php 5.4 environment handy, but load app_dev.php instead of app.php, as debugging will be set to true and errors will be reported.